# Автокликер на пайтон

Tags: python, клавиатура, мышь

Есть такой вот код

```
import keyboard
import mouse
import time

isClicking = False

def set_clicker():
    global isClicking
    if isClicking:
        isClicking = False
        print('Off')
    else:
        isClicking = True
        print('On')

keyboard.add_hotkey('Alt + z', set_clicker)

while True:
    if isClicking:
        mouse.double_click(button = 'left')
        time.sleep(0.6)
```

Но при запуске скрипта он не работает в игре(Родина РП)
Работает в браузере в папках везде кроме игры возможно ли что дело в полном окне?
И как мне сделать что бы я мог активировать в любой момент в любой програме на Виндовс?

Comment: Возможно "Alt + z" заняты в игре, и вы не можете всего навсего включить свой кликер.

Comment: Нет, я менял много раз комбинации всеравно..

Comment: вы нашли решение проблемы? я столкнулся с той же проблемой, и на мой взгляд, проблема в античите, который блокирует программное нажатие клавиатуры и мышки ...

Comment: Да, я уже давно все сделал, не помню в чем проблема вроде дать права администратора нужно IDE и тогда будет работать либо оконный режим